# Cannot empty rubbish bin

Tags: delete

I cannot empty the rubbish in 14.04 ubuntu. The files are from an external hdd - and I cannot remove them even if the drive is mounted.

Comment: Could you better explain exactly what is happening? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please accept the answer below instead of adding "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot empty the Rubbish Bin via the normal method (by clicking empty), navigate to the root of the drive in question and goto `View->Show Hidden Files` and check the box.

[image]

Then, delete any folders beginning with `.Trash-` such as `.Trash-1000`. You will be prompted for confirmation because the deletion is permanent.

[image]